# Simultaneous recording data in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

We have a table that one of its record by two systems at the same time is being to edited.
When the second system save the record, The first system have done all of that work be gone.
How to fix problem with linq.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is concurrency control. There are basically 2 ways to do it: pessimistic (lock data in database so no one can touch it) and optimistic (when you are updating an entity add a where clause with columns' original values or a a special timestamp [rowversion] column).

For entity framework you can find more information [in this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application),
and for linq-to-sql check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: His question is tagged linq-to-sql, not linq-to-entities.

Comment: Thank. But my question is tagged linq to sql

Comment: @MohammadJahangiry Sorry, I do not have experience with concurrency resolution in linq-to-sql, but quick googling seems to yeild some results. The basic idea is the same as with EF, so it should work ok. Check out this article for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373(v=vs.110).aspx